# Compare YYYYmm string with DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, compare

I have `YYYYmm` string and i want to compare datetime.

```cs
(MyDateTimeDate.Year == int.Parse(MyStringDate.Substring(0, 4))) &&
(MyDateTimeDate.Month > int.Parse(MyStringDate.Substring(MyStringDate.Length - 2)) ||
MyDateTimeDate.Year > int.Parse(MyStringDate.Substring(0, 4)));
```

I tried this method, but I did not get the correct result and the process took too long.

I'm trying to add the value 01 to the string and convert it to datetime and compare, but how to do it? Is it true logic?

Comment: Looks like your parenthesis are incorrect. The year can never be equal to _and_ greater than the YYYY part of `MyStringDate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse `MyStringDate` to `DateTime` with year and month i.e `yyyyMM`, Parsing will add default day as `1`, you need not to add `01` to string

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(myStringDate, "yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can check the condition,

```
(MyDateTimeDate.Year == dt.Year && 
  (MyDateTimeDate.Month > dt.Month || MyDateTimeDate.Year> dt.Year)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, to get the benefits of `DateTime` built-in comparison mecanisms, you should first convert both "dates" to a `DateTime` object that does not contain any problematic day or time information.

First, you can easily convert the `yyyyMM` string in this way:

```cs
var stringDate = "202207"; // An example.
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyyMM", null); 
// Gives 01/07/2022 00:00:00, so neutral day and time information.
```

Then you need to remove the particular day and time information of your other existing `DateTime` object, by creating a new `DateTime` where day is set to `1` and time to `00:00:00`:

```cs
var strippedDateTime= new DateTime(myDateTimeDate.Year, myDateTimeDate.Month, 1);
// Will set the date to the first of the month, and Time to OO:OO:OO
```

You can then use any comparison between the two date in a much more readable form:

```cs
if (parsedDateTime > strippedDateTime)
{
    // Do whatever.
}

// Or

if (parsedDateTime == strippedDateTime)
{
    // Do whatever.
}

// Etc... same princple for >=, <=, <
```